# Putting in a new 240v circuit for a dryer

Tags: electrical

The run is around 85 feet. Would #10-3 wire be ok to use or would I need to go with #8-3?

Answer (score 1):

### 10/3 will be more than fine

You won't start hitting voltage drop issues (upwards of 3%) on a 10AWG dryer circuit (~21A at 240V, using the Article 220 standard dryer load of 5kVA) until you hit about 160' of distance -- feel free to plug the numbers into your favorite voltage drop calculator and see what comes out.

Comment: Wow that is a long dryer run, I fully agree with 3phase as we have a horse blanket dryer in our barn 5kva, #10 copper is all we have and it only has about 2v drop when running but only about 120' from the panel.

Comment: Im only running around 85' but the guy at the store said that could only go 75' and i would need #8 and i didnt think he was right so just making sure.

Comment: @john welcome to home improvement store advice.  I've spoken to managers at real electrical supply houses - they say they recruit at big-box stores by playing dumb customers. When a clerk knows something, he hires them away.  Guess who that leaves.  Anyway, your guy was smarter than most, there's *some* reasonableness in that 75' number, that would apply to a **120V** circuit that is drawing the 100% full breaker-trip ampacity e.g. *actual 20A* on a 20A circuit.  Which is something you rarely do.

Answer (score 1):

What ThreePhaseEel said.  Keep in mind **your dryer current draw is 23 amps** That's true for almost every dryer made, since they are all aiming to be slightly underneath the 80% derate on a 30A circuit.

So be sure to use 23A when plugging into the Voltage Drop Calc.